# Show text based on option selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown like below.

```
<label for="form_name">Title</label>
<select class="bootstrap-select">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Feature 1</option>
  <option value="2">Feature 2</option>
  <option value="3">Feature 3</option>
  <option value="4">Feature 4</option>
</select>
<div><p>Text1</p></div>
<div><p>Text2</p></div>
<div><p>Text3</p></div>
<div><p>Text4</p></div>
```

I intend to show *Text 1* when *Feature 1* is selected, *Text 2* when *Feature 2* is selected and so on.

Any ideas on how can I do this with JS (or jQuery)?

P.S. Most existing solutions require input field rather than options field or maybe I am too noob. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `p` tags the `id` as the `value` of the `options`, and show the p tag when selected option has the value which is equal to the `id` of `p`

```js
$('p').hide();
$('#1').show();
$('select').change(function() {
$('p').hide();
  var a = $(this).val();
  $("#" + a).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="form_name">Title</label>
<select class="bootstrap-select">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Feature 1</option>
  <option value="2">Feature 2</option>
  <option value="3">Feature 3</option>
  <option value="4">Feature 4</option>
</select>
<div>
  <p id="1">Text1</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="2">Text2</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="3">Text3</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="4">Text4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi again. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work elsewhere. The snippet works here fine but doesn't in an html file. Any idea why? For e.g: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vgxogw

Comment: In the codepen first close the body tag, and just above the closing of the tag paste the script and remove it from the head. It will work

Comment: @Umer just a little warn with this example, if the select is by default on an other option you have to change the default id shown in your JS too. It's not dynamically based on the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript

```js
let select = document.querySelector("select");
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
let result = document.querySelector("#result");

function func1(par){
  result.innerText = divs[par - 1].innerText;
}
```

```css
div:not(#result) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<label for="form_name">Title</label>
<select class="bootstrap-select" onchange="func1(this.value)">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Feature 1</option>
  <option value="2">Feature 2</option>
  <option value="3">Feature 3</option>
  <option value="4">Feature 4</option>
</select>
<div><p>Text1</p></div>
<div><p>Text2</p></div>
<div><p>Text3</p></div>
<div><p>Text4</p></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry this doesn't work. The divs just jeep showing after another.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function display(){
    var e = document.getElementById("dropDownId");
    var index = e.selectedIndex;
    if(index==0){
        document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'none'
    }
    else if(index==1){
        document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'block'
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="form_name">Title</label>
<select class="bootstrap-select" id="dropDownId" onchange="display()">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Feature 1</option>
  <option value="2">Feature 2</option>
</select>
<div id="first"><p>Text1</p></div>
<div id="second" style="display: none;"><p>Text2</p></div>
```

Please run this snippet..and check out your solution..

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ids` on your `div` that you want to show and change the `value` of your `select` with the ids you choosed

```js
$("#select-panel").change(function(){
   updateDisplay();
})

function updateDisplay(){
  var idToShow = $("#select-panel").find(":selected").val() || "div1";
   $(".subcontent").each(function(){
      $(this).css("display",$(this).is("#"+idToShow) ? 'block' : 'none');
   })
}

updateDisplay();
```

```css
.subcontent{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-panel">
  <option value="div1">1</option>
  <option value="div2">2</option>
</select>
<div id="div1" class="subcontent">Text 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="subcontent">Text 2</div>
```

Comment: This works great but can Text 1 show at start since 1 is selected by default?